# what different between by viewmodel() and viewmode() and ViewModelProvider

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

now i studying MVVM and DataBinding and LiveData.
some blogs teach me how to declare method for viewmodel.
but why they have different method?

someone is use `ViewModelProvider` but someone is use `by viewModels()` and someone is create instance `viewModel()`

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(CardViewModel::class.java)
val viewModel = CardViewModel()
val viewModel : CardViewModel by viewModels()
```

and i tested it. and all is work!
what's different?

and last one(use `by viewModes()`) is very strange it.
is it like `lazy`?

Comment: The second one doesn't work at all: that won't save the ViewModel across config changes or call `onCleared()`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake ok what's the difference between provider and by viewmodels?

Comment: @Moataz - nothing